# MySQL optimizer not making use of ORDER BY soon enough

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I'm working with a couple tables dealing with customer orders. One table has the details of the order and the other has the shipping information.

I'm trying to select the most recent orders that are shipped out of a given warehouse. This is simple enough:

```
SELECT oi.* FROM order_info oi
INNER JOIN order_shipping_info osi ON osi.order_info_id = oi.id
WHERE osi.warehouse_id = 5
ORDER BY oi.order_date DESC LIMIT 100;
```

However, the problem I'm running into is that the number of rows in the table is magnitudes larger than the number of warehouses. MySQL determines that using the index on the warehouse_id column is not necessary and instead is doing a filesort which is grabbing 1.5M+ rows.

I would have assumed that the optimizer would start by sorting the `order_info` table (since the order_date column is indexed) and then work from there. That way, best case scenario, it grabs the first 100 rows it finds.

If I remove the WHERE clause, the query takes about 50ms to run. With the WHERE clause, it's closer to 3 seconds.

Is there a way I can force MySQL to do the ORDER BY first instead of the join?

Using MySQL 5.6

Comment: No, because you have to filter the data based on the `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wouldn't a composite index on (osi.order_info_id, osi.warehouse_id) help?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Help?  Yes.  Eliminate the sorting for the `ORDER BY`?  I doubt it.

Comment: This looks very familiar; did you ask this somewhere else?